# Issue with boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers

Simple way to make this issue:

1. Enable bolt factory addon.
2. Add a bolt
3. Add a simple cube mesh used for boolean modifier. This is used to cut away one quarter of the mesh from top view so position it as such.
4. Add boolean modifier (difference) to the bolt and nothing happens?

Sample file below:
https://we.tl/t-WfCUnRAOX5

Comment: Moving the cube slightly on the Y axis seems to 'fix' the problem. Also, the bolt contains some non manifold geometry : on top center, the 32 vertices share the same position but aren't connected ; you can fix it by merging them (Alt+M). That doesn't change anything in that specific situation, but booleans don't like non-manifold geomerty.

Comment: Don't know why, but this specific edge seems problematic : https://ibb.co/jV3KNp1
 Changing its position so it don't intersect with the edge of the cube make the boolean working.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Moving the cube little in y direction works. Moving that one edge did not change anything for me.

Comment: After moving the edge, you need to exit Edit mode for the boolean modifier to be refreshed.  Happy if that helped you, even if it's more a workaround than an answer.

Comment: I think boolean don't like overlapping edges or faces, which may explain